# My code to add sku to cart doesnt work anymore

Tags: woocommerce, skus

using woocommerce and before I would just use this code to have sku number show up on cart page. I would just add it in the functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_in_cart_product_title', 'add_sku_in_cart', 20, 3);
function add_sku_in_cart( $title, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
  $sku = $values['data']->get_sku();
  return $sku ? $title . sprintf(" (SKU: %s)", $sku) : $title;
}
```

Now I get this
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_sku() on a non-object in

I updated both my theme and woocommerce to latest version and then it erased the custom codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this $product_obj->get_sku();

Comment: Hi it doesn't seem to work for me when I add it, it gives same error.

Comment: add_filter( 'woocommerce_in_cart_product_title', 'add_sku_in_cart', 20, 3);
function add_sku_in_cart( $title, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
  $sku = $values['data']->$product_obj->get_sku();
  return $sku ? $title . sprintf(" (SKU: %s)", $sku) : $title;
}

Comment: how about echoing all of the variables to see what isnt populating? echo $values'.  '.$cart_item_key.'  '.$values['data'] etc?